# Disable "Auto remove aux files" dialog in TeXworks

Tags: errors, texworks, auxiliary-files

Every time LaTeX happens to generate a corrupted `.aux` file for whatever reason, the following dialog appears, reading _Whil tupesetting, a corrupt .aux file from a previous run was detected. You should remove it and rerun the typesetting process. Do you want to displaythe "Remove Aux Files..." dialog now?

[image]

Not only it is redundant (why not to display the other dialog immediately with `Skip` button?), but more importantly it is very annoying.

**I do not want any dialogs to appear!** Can it be switched off somehow or do I have to get the source, erase this part and recompile it?

Comment: Tom, I can't provide an answer right now, but the root of all evil relies on a hook named `logParser.js` inside `~/.TeXworks/scripts/Hooks`. You can either disable this hook via the `Scripts` menu or edit the corresponding code function and remove the `.aux` cleanup warning. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda You're my hero! Please, make it an answer. It suffices to add `return;` at the beginning of `LogParser.prototype.WarnAuxFiles` function in the file you mention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>From my comment to a proper answer. `:)`</sup>

The root of all evil relies on a hook named `logParser.js` inside `<USERHOME>/.TeXworks/scripts/Hooks`. If you are not sure where to find this path, TeXworks has a shortcut for it:

[image: Quack 1]

Namely, `Scripts ▶ Scripting TeXworks ▶ Show Scripts Folder`. Then you can access a folder named `Hooks` in there. Pretty easy, isn't it? `:)`

The file to blame is `logParser.js`,

[image: Quack 2]

which is a JavaScript code. We have two ways of dealing with it. Either by disabling the whole execution of this log parser via:

[image: Quack 3]

(`Scripts ▶ Scripting TeXworks ▶ Manage Scripts`)

And then unchecking the item `Errors, warnings, badboxes` under the `Hook Scripts` tab.

[image: Quack 4]

Or we can edit `logParser.js` directly. The function that deals with warning about auxiliary files is around line 373:

```js
LogParser.prototype.WarnAuxFiles = function()
{
  for (var i = this.Results.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (this.Results[i].Description.indexOf("File ended while scanning use of") > -1) {
      if (TW.question(null, "", "While typesetting, a corrupt .aux " +
        "file from a previous run was detected. You should remove " +
        "it and rerun the typesetting process. Do you want to display" +
        "the \"Remove Aux Files...\" dialog now?", 0x14000) == 0x4000)
        TW.target.removeAuxFiles();
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Although I could add a `return` statement right after the function body opening block, I'd favour commenting the offending parts. `:)` So:

```js
LogParser.prototype.WarnAuxFiles = function()
{
/*
No more! (Dr. Who, The Day Of The Doctor)

                        _.._
                       /   a\__,
                       \  -.___/
                        \  \
                   (\____)  \
               |\_(         ))
          _____|   (_        /________
               _\____(______/__
                    ______

  ooh a duck! :)

  for (var i = this.Results.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (this.Results[i].Description.indexOf("File ended while scanning use of") > -1) {
      if (TW.question(null, "", "While typesetting, a corrupt .aux " +
        "file from a previous run was detected. You should remove " +
        "it and rerun the typesetting process. Do you want to display" +
        "the \"Remove Aux Files...\" dialog now?", 0x14000) == 0x4000)
        TW.target.removeAuxFiles();
      break;
    }
  }
*/
}
```

And we are done. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem.

This problem may be caused by the errors in the typesetting process. In my case, if there is a mistake in the tex file, then I compile it, the typesetting process reports that error occurs and I stop typesetting, when I typesetting it again, the dialog appears to inform you to remove the aux file, actually if you click 'OK', another dialog will appear to choose which file should be removed, then you click 'Delete', all selected files will be deleted.

This problem may be inferred that:

- Error occurs in your typesetting process, it makes your aux files
  invalid. You should correct the error and remove the aux files, then
  typeset again.
- This dialog appears when you typeset the file in the second time
  after the error occurs.
- This dialog just inform you and actually the aux files will be
  deleted by the next dialog.

So my solution is that if error occurs in the typesetting process, when I abort it, the removing files dialog appears, then click 'delete' button to remove the aux files. (There is still a dialog because I find it hard to remove aux files by using the script and I don't know how to do it.)

And here is my code. The WarnAuxFiles function around line 373 in `logParser.js` is modified.

```
LogParser.prototype.WarnAuxFiles = function()
{
  for (var i = this.Results.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(this.Results[i].Severity == Severity.Error) {
        TW.target.removeAuxFiles();
        break;
    }
  }
}
```